# How to use only 10 bits of an int which is 2 bytes?

Tags: c, int, bit-manipulation

I got asked this in an interview. Assuming an int to be 2 bytes i.e. 16 bits, the interviewer wanted me to use only 10 bits of the integer which is basically restricting the range of the int. The other 6 bits would be unused of course.

Comment: Are you unfamiliar with bitwise operators?

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I was not clear. Let me clarify, the purpose is not to extract the 10 bits from an existing integer. But in fact make a new data type , say with typedef which would be an integer capable of storing only 10 bits.

Comment: Are you sure this is C and not C++?

Answer (score 0):

This is done by bit masking. ANDing would give you the results. To give an idea, to get the 8 most least significant bits from an integer you would AND with 0xff and so on.

Comment: I am sorry, maybe I was not clear. Let me clarify, the purpose is not to extract the 10 bits from an existing integer. But in fact make a new data type , say with typedef which would be an integer capable of storing only 10 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Your interviewer may have wanted you to demonstrate bit fields:

```
struct
{
    int a : 10;
} foo;
```

Seems like an odd feature to call out in an interview, but that's all I can think of.

And it may still not have the desired behavior, as the "10 bits" feature of it will only apply to storage, not to any operations you use it in.